# convert recursive function to the iteration form in python when getting maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop, iteration

i have a recursive function that calls itself but with one different input argument:

```
def invertCollapsedBlockMatrix(collapsedCovarianceMatrix , nGenes, nTimes, noise, acc=1):

    b = collapsedCovarianceMatrix[1:nTimes]
    ainverseb =(1/noise +(nGenes*inverseAcollapsed))* b #(6,1)

    cainverseb = nGenes*  ainverseb *b.reshape(-1,1)

    c=cainverseb[np.tril_indices(len(cainverseb))]
    ev=cov.flatten()[nTimes:nTimes+len(c)] - c
    logDetE,inverseE = invertCollapsedBlockMatrix(ev, nGenes, nTimes,noise)
    return logDetE,inverseE
```

when i run it, i get this error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

i tried to change the maximum recursion depth with

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)
```

but i get the same error. i'm still trying to write it in the iteration form

```
def invertCollapsedBlockMatrix(collapsedCovarianceMatrix , nGenes, nTimes, noise, acc1=1, acc2=1):
    while nTimes >1:
        b = collapsedCovarianceMatrix[1:nTimes]

        ainverseb =(1/noise +(nGenes*inverseAcollapsed))* b #(6,1)

        cainverseb = nGenes*  ainverseb *b.reshape(-1,1)


        c=cainverseb[np.tril_indices(len(cainverseb))]
        ev=cov.flatten()[nTimes:nTimes+len(c)] - c
        (collapsedCovarianceMatrix , nGenes, nTimes, noise, acc1, acc2)=(ev, nGenes, nTimes,noise, acc1, acc2)



    return acc1, acc2
```

however it doesn't work for me, it looks like an infinite while loop. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: you are not updating the `nTimes`

Comment: No matter whether you write it in iterative or recursive form, you need a clear condition for the process to *stop*. In your recursive attempt there is nothing that even tries to do this - the function calls itself once recursively no matter what. In the iterative form, you try to control the loop with `while nTimes > 1:`, but there is nothing that could cause `nTimes` to change at all, and certainly not to make it `<= 1` as would be needed to stop. You need, first of all, to be able to explain *clearly, in plain language*, how the code is supposed to work and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: i tried to update nTimes and to fix a condition for the process to stop (nTimes is decremented), i wrote if nTimes <=1, it returns some values, else while nTimes <=5 it treats  instructions above until logDetE,inverseE = invertCollapsedBlockMatrix(ev, nGenes, nTimes,noise) then, i made nTimes=nTimes-1, and return logDetE,inverseE,   i think it normally should stop, however it looks like an infinite loop again, can someone help me ?

Comment: i didn't understand why it's an infinite loop ? i thought that if nTimes <=1 it returns the if bloc and the else bloc will be treated if nTimes is 2 or 3 ou 4 or 5